# javascript ajax call before send is not executed

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this Javascript code:

```
this.confirmBox = function(data) {
  $.jconfirm((function(_this) {
    return function() {
      var objConfig;
      objConfig = $.jconfirm("getConfig");
      alert("here");
      return true;
    };
  })(this));
  return false;
};

this.beforeSend = function(event, jqXHR) {
  if (this.confirmBox()) {
    return this.disableSubmit();
  } else {
    return jqXHR.abort();
  }
};
```

When I run the script I am landing on `alert("here")` and `return true` for the function confirmBox.

The problem however is that the ajax call itself is not triggered anymore for some reason. How do I need to adjust the beforeSend function in order to check if the checkBox result is true or false?

Comment: take the value of `this.disableSubmit()` in a `var` and debug to find out it's value. Return the var later on.

Comment: @theghostofc - thank you. The `this.disableSubmit()` is not causing the problem that the ajax call is no longer triggered. I am not sure but it might be that I do not check correctly in the beforeSend function if the confirmBox function is true/false?

Comment: I think inside the beforeSend method, you're using 'this' which refers to the same method (beforeSend)

Comment: @NitsanBaleli - I have adjusted the code and question. Can you tell me  how do I need to adjust the beforeSend function in order to check if the result function within the checkBox function is true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the event on the buttons
Please see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/vvjj8/) fiddle example

```
buttons: {
        "Yes": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            callback(true);
        },
            "No": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            callback(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use the free jConfirm found at http://riggerthegeek.github.io/jConfirm/examples.html
it does not cost most like the plugin of evato you are using and much simpler.

Comment: this looks good! let me implement this and get back to you in case your solution above should not work.

Comment: I have updated my initial post with the jconfirm plugin. I have the same issue like with the paid one before. How can I tell the function beforeSend that the user clicked confirmed now?

Answer (score 1):

I think call to confirmBox method in beforeSend always returns false because $.msgbox does not block thread execution like window.confirm method does. Probably you need to invoke ajax call when you get the result === "Confirm" from message box.

```
$.msgbox("confirm", {
    type: "confirm",
    buttons: [
        { type: "cancel", value: "Cancel" }, 
        { type: "submit", value: "Confirm" }
    ]}, function(result) {
        if (result === "Confirm") {
            // $.ajax(..)
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, the OP needs to pass success and fail callback functions from beforeSend to confirmBox and include them in the callbacks supplied to MsgBox.  See https://github.com/composite/jQuery.MsgBox/wiki

Comment: @Paul - I am using jquery.msgbox.js

Comment: @Mihir - thank you. Could you give me an example on how to achieve this?

Comment: It looks like `$.confirm(message, function(bool))` would be easier to use here than `$.msgbox`;  both are provided by the msgbox plugin.

Comment: @Paul - I am using [msgBox Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-msgbox/92626)

Comment: Agreed with @Paul, updating answer with an example.

Comment: @domi771 Your link connects to a paid code site.  I was talking about the code available under the (open source) MIT license from https://github.com/composite/jQuery.MsgBox.  Code Canyon can sell it, but can't change the license.  Really no reason to pay anyone $6 for it.... especially anyone other than the author.

Comment: @Paul - Thank you. I have updated my initial code/question with a free version as proposed by Scription. The problem remains the same however.

Comment: @domi771 I updated code sample to use with your existing plugin

Comment: @Mihir - thank you but I can't use the code like this since I need to make a callback to the beforeSend function and I dont know how to achieve this